# Error when checking input: expected conv1d_11_input to have shape (6700, 1) but got array with shape (1, 1)

Tags: keras

Iam using 1dCNN for time series data but following error occur in `model.fit line`.
The error is as follows :

`Error when checking input: expected conv1d_11_input to have shape (6700, 1) 
 but got array with shape (1, 1)`.

any one plz help
code portion is as below

```
    dataframe = pd.read_excel("file path", header=None,delim_whitespace=True)
    dataset = dataframe.values
    X=dataframe.values[:,0]
    Y=dataframe.values[:,2]
    X = np.expand_dims(X, axis=1)
    Y = np.expand_dims(Y, axis=1)
    (X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test) = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=seed)
    X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (-1, X_train.shape[1],1))
    Y_train = np.reshape(Y_train, (Y_train.shape[0], 1, Y_train.shape[1]))
    X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], 1, X_test.shape[1]))
    print(X_train.shape)
    print(Y_train.shape)
    n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], Y_train.shape[1]
    verbose, epochs, batch_size = 0, 100, 32
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_timesteps,1)))
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

`n_timesteps, n_outputs = X_train.shape[1], Y_train.shape[1]`

Comment: whats the output of `print(X_train.shape)` ?

Comment: It is     (6700, 1, 1)

Comment: so, you want to use CNN to train data points with only one feature of dimension 1?

Comment: for series, you can try RNN, LSTM, etc. CNNs are barely used for this purpose.

Comment: whats the shape of Y_train?

Comment: it is also (6700,1,1)

Comment: I don't see how you would make use of CNNs here.. I think you should try your hands on RNN or LSTM / GRU, etc